# Regarding the Static Full Adder Circuit

Tags: cmos, adder

**As per the book on Digital Integrated Circuits by Rabaey Et al.** in the static CMOS implementation of Full adder circuit with Co= carry out and S= Sum
[image]
As mentioned in the marked point of the attached image, the intrinsic load capacitance of the Co signal is 2 diffusion and 6 gate capacitances, plus the wiring capacitance.

- Can anyone please explain how are these 2 diffusion and 6 gate capacitance are occuring?
- What are the transistor sizes for this circuit?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The claim *the circuit is slow* contains a mention of *ripple-carry adder*:

- it is assumed that \$C_o\$ is routed to \$C_i\$ of exactly one identical adder.
  I think it easy to count six gates labelled \$C_i\$.
- lamenting the capacitive load on \$C_o\$ suggests to make the transistors driving it wider.

Figure 11-4 doesn't literally implement \$C_o = AB + BC_i + AC_i\$, but an odd mix of
\$C_o = (A + B)C_i + AB\$ (N, pull-down) and \$C_o = (A + B)(AB + C_i)\$ (P, pull-up)

You can reduce the number of gates driven by \$C_i\$ by one or [two](https://www.falstad.com/circuit/circuitjs.html?ctz=CQAgjCAMB0l3BWc0DscBMkDMBOHAWOAydEBSMsihAUwFowwAoAMxHQA4OR8cA2EFiwDeAhKTDQkMEq0F9uonmBH8yEqVFjommFOy4816BKpEgAgrsj7hitULM8QAISYB3ZWLCl8K9dyQHoLCZD4hYpxQwY4BXnFBAObx4or+CPj4UNGesfgcFHl8WUG5ofjF8RUlwX4iBVWVpY1ZdTz50Wx2PFi+-vi96sjS2rX94yJwnfLc3W3dCFjDWrKebYQU8xw1uQo9pHNTzYeFe91BbAO+avmbauLLMjq7ioNX+zkf799qzW2pPAaAL+QKitzCpD+-SmSg20wyrTeN0GD0kI1kbARRicSlRmiecixpjuYj41A06J0yVxKCcCBwkM+uMy2IhTJuDVhHRBm05HIofxu-RuR2s+iJZLItLIkqybj0ZBZNJxljFisRpAQ0u+IAAwgBLQksuYOPaLR6jNYObasuHNLELJWDC4fXq8wqYMhLNErZ4zf3vc61QZzEOewUCPINWI8wSQVoNEwCF0Oz1KN1ei0Y9XsFDXAToPOZn0Eq2Rh7p0IRuOtYyGKHlvoFwjsgumVnoFtBBWp6jSjNytVYwua6Uj5xWMs8Kb03yigAy4HC7yFyfAIBYAEMADYAZxolGOezhYG1ooAHrmDgzczhBDgkFlwgANNXoTsfJNfVUK9+1tsqm4bB-qyp50hSvpyCB7xgR8eKUsEsHgkh3KIdq-hIaKniYRQsFYDaLogd0eFmt6+KWuA-aomOXZMIujD5iA-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-t5osM+EAduFzRvappAr89QF1aML+vNhJtO0VOX6i+2QRHTtRY7VnsdXQKN1AA%5D) duplicating one or both of the "internal \$\neg C_o\$ (X) transistors".

Comment: (I fail to see *2 diffusion capacitances* - yet.) (Going to try and reduce #gate on \$C_i\$.)

Comment: The diffusion cap is the inverter driving Co.  Yeah, I would not consider this load per se, but on the other hand, it's capacitive, and if it were a complex gate with a single device trying to swing a heavily-dotted output, then it does matter.   Like the complex gates shown here tend to have the parallel devices pushed away from the output towards the supplies to reduce "load" on X and S-bar.